# Is there a tool to change a CAML query and bind it to its view?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, caml

I created a view in a Sharepoint 2007 (SP) list, I included some filters in this view.
Internally, SP have generated a CAML. I need to change this generated CAML and include more complex conditions in the where clause, after that, I have to save it to the view and then, test the results.

Is there a tool that let me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno if this helps - for Development using SP Web Services, we previously used the [U2U CAML generator](http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Patrick/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1252) on MOSS2007.

However, it seems there is a new tool on [CodePlex - CAML Generator](http://camlgenerator.codeplex.com/)

But I haven't developed in SP for a while tho ...

Comment: thanks nonnb, please let me ask you if you know about an executable tool (.exe). Thanks!!

Comment: You can download the CAML generator App here - you need SP installed http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/karine/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=d35935e0-8c0e-4176-a7e8-2ee90b3c8e5a&ID=30

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a tool that is an advanced version of the out of the box ViewEdit.aspx page, I do not know that such a tool exists.

If you want to create a custom List Definition, then I would [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) or [STSDEV](http://stsdev.codeplex.com/) to create the feature and solution package for your custom List Definition containing the CAML generated by the [U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx).